# Debugging random crashes on AppGyver steroids/supersonic

Tags: steroids, appgyver, supersonic

I have developed a single-page app on the appgyver steroids platform. For some reason, the app frequently crashes on iPhone 6 and the iPhone 6 plus. It does crash sometimes on the iPhone 5s. These crashes are quite random.

I have built a custom appgyver debug scanner build, but unable to find anything significant related to the crash. In xcode device logs, I noticed this:

```
 Name       |            <UUID>                |     CPU Time|     rpages|       purgeable| recent_max| lifetime_max| fds |  [reason]         | (state)
    MyApp <db4034ffab78564f8c99db20e8d2b040>       117.395      166401                0           -        151979  100  [per-process-limit]  (frontmost) (resume)
```

How can I debug the app somehow to find the cause of this crash?

Comment: Does the simulator crash?

Comment: No, the simulator works as expected.